# JOOQ Window Partition ORDER DESC

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I try to formulate the following PostgreSQL Query into JOOQ:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY propertyid ORDER BY validfrom DESC) 
        AS rownum FROM propertyvalue WHERE validfrom <= '1978-01-01T00:00:00Z') X
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

So I want to write a query with a nested query which uses window functions and start with the inner query first. I came that far:

```
ctx.select(PROPERTYALUE.fields(), DSL.rowNumber().over().
       partitionBy(PROPERTYVALUE.propertyid).orderBy(PROPERTYVALUE.validfrom).???)
```

After the orderBy command, I don't have a DESC option to be used anymore in JOOQ. There are just commands like `rangeFollowing` or `rowsCurrentRow` and an inherited command like `desc()` which returns a SortField-object on which I can't call my required subsequent commands anymore.

So is there any way in JOOQ to formulate my desired SQL query with the DESC order in a window function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write this:

```java
DSL.rowNumber()
   .over()
   .partitionBy(PROPERTYVALUE.propertyid)
   .orderBy(PROPERTYVALUE.validfrom.desc()))
```

Observe the fact that I called `desc()` on the column `validfrom` in order to pass the resulting `SortField` to the `orderBy()` clause of the window function call.

What you tried to do would have been to order by the window function expression, e.g. in an `ORDER BY` clause of the `SELECT` statement. E.g.:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM propertyvalue 
WHERE validfrom <= '1978-01-01T00:00:00Z'
ORDER BY row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY propertyid ORDER BY validfrom) DESC
```